# Extend the __init__ of a class to accept more keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to extend a larger set of classes to accept an additional keyword argument. The set of classes all share a common interface which I cannot change.

I have tried it like this:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=1, c=2):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c



def extended_base ( Kls ):

    additional_fields = [ 'a', 'b' ]

    def my_init( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        for field in additional_fields:
            try:
                setattr(self, '{}2'.format(field), kwargs.pop(field))
            except KeyError:
                setattr(self, '{}2'.format(field), None)

        # Does not work as I expect
        # super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Does not work as expected 
        super(Kls, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    # I would like to define a function that returns a function that does
    # what the following functions do, automatically but for every value
    # in `additional_fields` 
    def get_a2( self ):
        return self.a2 or self.a
    def get_b2( self ):
        return self.b2 or self.b

    return type( 'My{}'.format(Kls.__name__), (Kls, ), {
        '__init__' : my_init,
        'get_a2' : get_a2,
        'get_b2' : get_b2,

    })


test = extended_base(Base)(a=3, a2=9)
test.a
test.a2
test.get_a2()

test.get_b2()
```

As you see, I just want to extend some properties of the base class, and I would love to be able to do this by simply specifying the properties that should be extended in the `additional_fields` of the function.

I have two problems: I do not know how to call the parents `__init__` method, the two ways shown above both give errors The second is, I do not know how to define an anonymous(?) function that would, for example, do the same for the property `c` if I add `c` to the `additional_fields`-list.

Comment: You need a `__init__` method probably

Comment: @mad_ Well, there are `__init__` methods everywhere I can imagine. But obviously my imagination is not correct.